# Can client deserialize const fields from a WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a client that has to access the public const field of a class from a WCF, but when I reference the WCF the fields don't appear in the client, even using [DataMember] in all fields.

```
    [DataContract]
    [Serializable]
    public class ProductTypes
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
        public const int UNKNOWN = 0;

        [DataMember]
        public const int EC_PF_VALEBROKER = 1;

        [DataMember]
        public const int EC_PC_IRCALC = 2;

        [DataMember]
        public const int EC_PR_VALEBROKERPRO = 3;

        [DataMember]
        public const int EC_PF_MOBILEBROKER = 4;

        [DataMember]
        public const int EC_PF_VALEBROKERPLATAFORM = 5;
}
```

Comment: Const is not a member of an instance, it's member of class (like static field) and so should not be included when deserializing.

Comment: That's a weird request for a *lot* of reasons. 1)  Fields are for *private* use and storage. They aren't considered part of the class's or DTO's contract.. Client proxies will generate properties whether you use fields or properties simply because XSD does *not* say anything about how the DTOs are implemented.

Comment: 2) if you want to say that `ProductType` has a range of valid values, a const is an extremely bad idea. A const never changes. Type values do. One constant says nothing about other constants or the enclosing type either.

Comment: 3) Value restrictions, choices etc are *already* supported in XSD. Clients know how to handle them. Don't invent your own serialization format.

Comment: Check [Enumerations in Data Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts)